# C# DateTime AddDays off by one

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain to me why this unit test is failing?

I scoured through MSDN expecting to find an explanation, for example I was expecting to find something like, "the starting day is not inclusive" etc. but I found no such statement. Therefore I am confused as to why this seems to be off by one day.

The following will result in Sept 29th. I am expecting Sept 30th.

```
[Test]
public void AddDaysBug_OffByOne()
{
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2018,10,3);

    DateTime fourDaysEarlier = end.AddDays(-4);

    // this fails. 29!=30
    Assert.AreEqual(fourDaysEarlier.Day,30, "four days prior to October 3 is Sept 30");
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect `-4` to result in the 30th?  Is there a zero day each month I am not aware of?  [See for yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JSKAVd)

Comment: The result is correct, the four prior days are "Oct 2", "Oct 1", "Sept 30" and finally "Sept 29", those are the 4 prior days and is what `AddDays` is doing.

Comment: I see. I believe my confusion stems from thinking like a human. For example if it is Oct 3rd and a person asks me, "what were you doing 4 days ago?" I will think they are asking me about Sept 30. However, that is a mistake to think like a human. In this case the code does not "count" Oct 3rd as a human would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take these days one at a time for illustration...

3rd - 1 = 2nd
2nd - 1 = 1st
1st - 1 = 30th
30th - 1 = 29th

There is no zero day in months as with "normal" numbers.

Comment: Why do you not count Oct 3rd as a day, also? If it is 11:59PM on Oct 3rd, do we simply not care about the 23 hours and 59 minutes?

Comment: @sapbucket - What do you mean? This does take the 3rd into account. Even if you had Oct 3 23:59 as a time, 4 days less is still Sept 29th (but also at 23:59). You're subtracting whole days at a time, so time of day obviously isn't going to matter.

Comment: 3rd = 1 day, 2nd = 2 day, 1st = 3 day, 30th = 4 day...?

Comment: I see the logic now. I will mark this correct answer.

Comment: @sapbucket why would the 3rd be one day?  Today _is the third_.  Minus 24 hours from now would be the 2nd (i.e yesterday)...

Comment: It's not that the 3rd is one full day - but it is a day...am I not allowed to say "today" is a day, just because it hasn't expired yet?

Comment: @sapbucket of course today is a day, just like any other day.  But if you minus one day from today, it would be yesterday, not today.  Just look at it like math.  Today is 3.  If you minus 1 from 3, you get 2.

Comment: i think what you mean is that you are subtracting 24 hours, not a "day".

Comment: @sapbucket that does not make sense either.  A "day" _is the same thing_ as 24 hours.  I am sincerely trying to figure out your original thought process

Comment: Subtracting a *day* is the same as 24 *hours*. Note sure why that would be up for debate otherwise. If you had done `.AddHours(24 * -4)` instead of `.AddDays(-4)`, you'd get the *exact same* answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Setp**:  28, 29, 30

**Oct**: 1, 2, 3

**So**: (3 Oct - 4 day) is equal to 29

Answer (score 0):

Sept 29th seems to be correct answer.

It's easy to see if you subtracting one day at a time.

-1 day, 10/02/2018

-2 day, 10/01/2018

-3 day, 09/30/2018

-4 day, 09/29/2018